# How to complement bytes in java?

Tags: java, binary, byte, xor

I need to complement string binaries.

`st=br.readLine() //I used readline to read string line`

`byte[] bytesy = st.getBytes(); //and put it to bytes array.`

Now how can I complement the binary equivalent of the bytes (or how to XOR it to 11111111) ?

Expected output :

If first char of st is  x then binary equivalent is 01111000

and the output must be 10000111 by complementing ( or XOR to 11111111)

Comment: The XOR operator in java is '^'

Comment: It's bizarre to read binary data using a reader and readLine. Also, getBytes uses the platform's default encoding. You might have to specify an encoding to transform the string into bytes and make the code portable.

Comment: but i don't know how to XOR to 11111111. because.. do you know how to convert string "11111111" to byte?

Comment: Do *not* use `String.getBytes()` without specifying an encoding. It will use the platform default, which is almost certainly not what you want. Please give more information about what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: i need to XOR every single char of string to 11111111(binary) to compliment char binary.

Comment: @JB: I'd simply say say "wrong" instead of "bizarre".

Comment: @Joachim: maybe he wants to "encrypt" lines of text, in which case it would be right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To complement a byte, you use the `~` operator. So if x is 01111000, then `~x` is 10000111. For XORing you can use `x ^= 0xFF` (11111111b == 0xFF in hex)

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a loop to do it one byte at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have numbers as binary such as "111111" you can perform twos-compliment without converting it to a number.  You can do this.

```
BufferedReader br = 
int ch;
while((ch = br.read()) >= 0) {
   switch(ch) {
      case '0': ch = '1'; break;
      case '1': ch = '0'; break;
   }
   System.out.print(ch);
}
```